# UnboundField object error with dynamic forms

Tags: python, flask

I have a dynamic form:

```
class CollectionRequestParamForm(Form):
    param_human_name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    param_request_name = StringField()


class CollectionRequestParamCombinedForm(FlaskForm):
    params = FieldList(FormField(CollectionRequestParamForm), min_entries=2)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And I want to set `min_entries` from code in view, like:

```
collection_request_params_form = CollectionRequestParamCombinedForm(min_entries=5)
```

I do this:

```
class CollectionRequestParamCombinedForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, min_entries, *args, **kwargs):
        FlaskForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.params = FieldList(FormField(CollectionRequestParamForm), min_entries=min_entries)

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

But: `TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not iterable`

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

do this if you want to make it dynamic

```
for i in range(min_entries):
    form.params.append_entry()
```

more for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710958/9218468