# Flask wtforms - 'UnboundField' object is not callable, dynamic field won't init properly

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, FieldList, FormField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'apple pie'


class BookForm(FlaskForm):
    book = StringField('book title')


class LibraryForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, min_entries=0, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LibraryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.books = FieldList(FormField(BookForm), min_entries=min_entries)

    library = StringField('Library name')
    books = FieldList(FormField(BookForm), min_entries=3)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/book', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def book():
    form = LibraryForm(min_entries=5)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'aww yeah'
    return render_template('books.html', form=form)
```

books.html

```
<html>
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div>{{ form.library.label }}: {{ form.library() }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.books.label }}: {{ form.books() }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.submit.label }}: {{ form.submit() }}</div>
</html>
```

My goal is to make my form init with a flexible number of entries, such as in the example shown in the link. Whenever I run my code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not callable
```

When I comment out the **init** function, the form works as expected, apart from the non-flexible amount of Book Fields. I've spent quite some time looking for answers, but couldn't find any which solved the problem.

[example of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSGrK.png)

Any help is appeciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the ideal solution, but this works though.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, FieldList, FormField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'apple pie'


class BookForm(FlaskForm):
    book = StringField('book title')


class LibraryForm(FlaskForm):
    library = StringField('Library name')
    books = FieldList(FormField(BookForm))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/book', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def book():
    form = LibraryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'aww yeah'
    for i in range(6):
        form.books.append_entry()

    return render_template('books.html', form = form)
```